# Ubuntu not booting, displaying mariadb server error

Tags: boot, mariadb

After rebuilding docker Ubuntu stopped booting and showing this with blinking monitor
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/352mA.jpg)
I tried enter ubuntu advanced mode and remove maria-db with following commands, but nothing helped

```
apt-get remove mariadb-server
apt-get remove mariadb
apt-get remove mariadb-service
```

How can I fix that without OS reinstallation?

Updated: after trying to purge and disabling mariadb got this screen [New Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAFha.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purge mariadb if you want to remove it completely:

```
sudo apt purge mariadb
```

But you could also disable mariadb service, so it will not be trying to start:

```
sudo systemctl disable mariadb
```

Output:

```
[sudo] password for user: 
Removed /etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service.
Removed /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mariadb.service.
```

Reinstall gdm3 package by purging it and installing again:

```
sudo apt purge gdm3 && sudo apt install gdm3
```

Also try installing lightdm, switch to it and try.

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

If it is installed, you could switch to it the next way:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Comment: tried to disable mariadb, the error screen still persists, but without mariadb error

Comment: Ok. Try reinstalling gdm3 and, if not helpful, try to switch to lightdm.